# Simple app for viewing JPG and then deleting JPG+RAW files simultaneously?

Tags: software, preview

Does anyone know of a simple photo viewer that will let you quickly flip through a bunch of photos, and delete the ones you don't want, that will also (optionally) delete an associated RAW and/or sidecar file?

I'm thinking of an app that had a buttons for Delete JPG, Delete RAW, Delete Both, or that would mark them for deletion to perform before exiting the app, or something similar to that.

Edit: Windows Vista (soon to be Windows 7), camera is Nikon D90 (so .NEF raw files).  I have not instaleld the bundled Nikon software yet.  I've just been using the Windows photo import which just copies them onto the hard drive.  If I preview using Windows Photo Gallery, deleting the file only deletes the JPG, so I have to go back and delete the raw files manually afterwards.

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: On Windows 7, that's all built in (between the photo viewer and the "extra large thumbnails").  I frequently do this from the laptop without removing the pictures from the camera.  (It's hard to recognize a great pic from a thumbnail, but it's dirt simple to recognize total crap)  And considering how the Mac is aimed at art and media, I'd be willing to bet that it's built in there too.

Comment: @HiredMind that's why I asked for clarification on OS -- Windows Explorer can do this for Canon/Nikon RAW since XP (with a small additional add-on from Microsoft) and also in Vista (with the RAW plugin from most vendors, or even some third parties)

Comment: If you have Mac, Preview does it all. And preview comes standard on Macs.

Comment: @Rowland: Vista (see edit to original post).  Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/q/41200/302

Comment: @HiredMind - "It's hard to recognize a great pic from a thumbnail, but it's dirt simple to recognize total crap" - Love it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was a way to view the photos (but only view one copy, not both the JPG and the RAW version), and then having both the RAW and JPG files deleted at the same time when I chose to delete the photo.

It doesn't appear there is any simple/cheap way to do this, but I do have Lightroom, so I just import everything, and Lightroom is smart enough to "bundle" the JPG/RAW, preview only one image of each photo, and will delete both files when asked.

Answer (score 5):

You can get this for free with XnView: I have now written an easy tutorial to configure everything properly: http://ubuntuswitch.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/delete-jpg-and-raw-files-simultaneously-on-windows/

Works like a charm :-)

**Edit for Paul Cezanne**: I do not have any plans to take the blog down, as I use it as reference for such problems, but here is the relevant text from the above mentioned post:

Use [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/de/xnview/). After installing do the following:

1. Open the XnView-config file: `%appdata%\XnView\xnview.ini` (in my case `C:\Users\alex\AppData\Roaming\XnView\xnview.ini`).
2. In the section [File] add a new line at the end: `Companion_00=jpg:cr2`
   This links the .cr2 (raw-File) to the .jpg. So if you delete the jpg it automatically deletes the .cr2. Replace the cr2 with the extension of your raw-file (so eg nef for Nikon) and save the file.

   > If you want the effect also in the other direction you have to create
   >   another newline:  Companion_01=cr2:jpg. For now you can just leave
   >   this, as we will hide the raw files in the next steps.
3. Start XnView and open the options (Menu: Tools > Options or via ).

   1. In General open the tab File Operations tick the checkbox “For Copy/Move/Delete use companion file (.xmp/.thm/.jpg)
   2. In Browser > File List write the file extension you want to hide (the raw file: in my case cr2) in the last text input and click the OK button.

That is it. Now it should be easier to sort your pictures, as only the jpg-pictures are shown and if you delete it, the raw file automatically gets also deleted.

Comment: Hi, welcome to photo.stackexchange.com. Great write up, but just in case your blog disappears, would you mind copy/pasting the text into here? Keep the link though, that way readers here can still find you there. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Geeqie](http://geeqie.sourceforge.net/) can do this -- turn on the "Enable Image Grouping" option, and files with the same base name will be grouped. (It doesn't do anything magic to link files by actual contents that I'm aware of, though.)

You should be able to install it with `yum install geeqie` or `apt-get install geeqie` on Fedora or Ubuntu. I'm not aware of pre-built packages for Mac or Windows, but in theory it should be possible.

Comment: It appears @seanmc is after a Windows solution, so this won't work for him.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.irfanview.com/

Options - Properties/Settings - File Handling - Delete - For Experts: delete "sidecar files"

Check the box and enter your camera's raw file extension and JPG, like so - `CR2|JPG|`

Or in your case `NEF|JPG|`

Works for me. great photo viewer and the price is right!

Answer (score 1):

"a simple photo viewer that will let you quickly flip through a bunch of photos, and delete the ones you don't want" - isn't this built in for every camera's bundled software? Canon's ZoomBrowser can do this easily, for jpegs and RAWs.

For the optional part - it can't, to the best of my knowledge, mark for later deletion.

Comment: It appears @seanmc is after a Nikon solution, so this won't work for him.

Comment: On the other hand, it does add value to the site as a whole to give more generally-useful answers like this.  (As a canon guy, I appreciated this one  :) +1

Answer (score 1):

With a NEF codec installed, the NEF files will show up in Windows Photo Gallery right along side your JPEGs.

If you are on 64 bit Windows 7 or Vista, you may want to try out our commercial NEF codec, which is many times faster than Nikon's.

A free trial is available.  http://www.ardfry.com/nef-codec

Answer (score 0):

[FastPictureViewer](http://www.fastpictureviewer.com/) groups JPG and RAW files similar to Lightroom and, I suppose, deletes both simultaneously. Of course, it does not do everything Lightroom does, but it comes at a much lower price.

Answer (score 0):

They say Photo Mechanic 5 is the king for this kind of job. At least professional sports reporters do. It comes with a higher price tag though. I am on the trial run right now but trying to make Xnview MP works the way I want.

@ Alexander Taubenkorb. I am trying to duplicate the steps you have provided but I am afraid that if I only have CR2 files in the folder (sometimes I shoot just raw if I know I need to edit, paid job) I may not see them in Xnview if they are hidden. I could then by mistake delete "empty" folder with hidden CR2 files...

Another point as I cant comment on someone else post for some stupid remutation points I wanted to add this information:
Adding Companion_00=jpg:cr2 will copy the cr2 but with lowercase extension. It will also stop copying / deleting xmp files.

In order to have both CR2 and XMP files with Uppercase extensions copied / deleted please add to xnview.ini these two lines

`Companion_00=JPG:CR2
 Companion_01=JPG:XMP`

Answer (score -1):

All you need do is install the [Nikon RAW codec](http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/index.html.en), and you can then view thumbnails in Explorer, and double click to open a full size view.

It may also be worth having a play with the trial version of Adobe Lightroom, as it is awesome for keywording, and making minor adjustments - you don't even need to worry about it being in RAW or JPEG then, as it silently handles it (it also isn't limited to 32-bit installations, unlike Nikon's RAW codec)

Comment: I don't need to preview the RAW image, but I'm looking to have the RAW image automatically deleted when I delete the JPG.  Can Explorer do that with the RAW codec?  Can Lightroom?  Thanks!

Comment: My point is that if you use the RAW codec, you don't even need the JPEG as you will be previewing the single image file

Comment: I like shooting JPG plus RAW, because most of the time it is convenient just to have the JPG to review and/or email or upload, and still have the RAW if I want to do more extensive post-processing.  I was just looking for a way to quickly review and then delete the JPG+RAW simultaneously for photos that aren't worth saving at all.